# ScrollView error when I have used ScrollView in both fragments

Tags: java, android, scrollview, android-scrollview

Can anyone help me to solve this?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct
> child

I get this error because I have used ScrollView in both fragments. How to solve this?

I have to use ScrollView in both fragments, but I can't. Is there any way? I can't move from one fragment to another. If I tried to do so then the following exception is thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct
> child

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what the problem really is without being able to read your code, but I bet you have a  tag with multiple tags inside it.

If for example you have something like this:

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <LinearLayout
                        ...
           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
                        ...
           </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Try switching to this:

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <LinearLayout
                        ...
           </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ScrollView tags only allow one direct child for each. Avoid using nested ScrollViews too